# WIX maintain SQLite database after Update of Windows Installer

Tags: c#, sqlite, wix, windows-installer

`Description:` I have made a Windows Installer using WIX Toolset. There is a database file made within the .NET application and downloaded on the client machine along with the application after installation. The application runs and new data is entered in the database file. The application is also made available for updates.

`Problem:` After installing the updated application on the client machine, I want the data in the database to be maintained(specifically if a new column is added). There should be no loss of the new data after the update of the application. What i want is to maintain the new added column too by matching the data from the old and new database files and adding the new data in the file.

`Attempt:` The row data is getting maintained after the update of the application.

`Question:` How to go about matching the old database file and the new one and maintaining columns too.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how and when exactly you are downloading/creating the database file?

Comment: If you can change the application, then probably it would be easier to make this update by the application itself.